# Def main(): Giving me errors

Tags: python

```
def Main()
    import pyautogui, time
    import uuid
    import random
    import string
    import os
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    start = timer()
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    i = 0
    a = ''
    while i < 15:
        a += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        i += 1
    print(email.lower())
    ...

Main()
```

I want to define `Main` and then at the end of my source code go back to main.
I have tried the solution as shown above but I get a syntax error.
I am fairly new to Python.

Comment: Can u show the error? I guess error may be due to syntax

Comment: A colon is required after def, like so: `def main():`  Also the following lines must be indented, or they aren't part of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntactical errors. Try the following code.

```
import pyautogui, time
import uuid
import random
import string
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer
email = 'some_email@some.com'
def Main():
    start = timer()
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    i = 0
    a = ''
    while i < 15:
        a += random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        i += 1
    print(email.lower())
Main()
```

Comment: Thanks so a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited the code because in your code the variable email is not defined. It will throw an error: NameError: name 'email' is not defined

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting now? Please make sure that the variable email is define to some value.